# Typeface returns fatal coding errors after update of LaTeX core

Tags: fonts, typefaces

For several years I have used the `typeface` package to load the fonts I like to use in my documents and to prevent the occurrence of math font related errors. Until about July 2022 my MikTeX distribution allowed the use of that package.

However after an update in July 2022 `typeface` didn't work anymore giving two errors in the code of the package:

`line 825 Missing control sequence inserted. ...ption}{rm,sf,tt,math,symbols,textfigures}` and
`line 929 Missing control sequence inserted. ...fontencoding,inputencoding,textcomp,cmap}`

These lines contain the coding:
`\forcsvlist{\tf@reconfigurefontoption}{rm,sf,tt,math,symbols,textfigures}` (line 825) and `\forcsvlist{\tf@@pkgoptionsvalidation}{fontencoding,inputencoding,textcomp,cmap}` (line 929).

Now, I can circumvent these fatal errors by loading the font packages the usual way. But that does result in errors using `gfsartemisia` in combination with `chemfig` (see question [Chemfig causes problems in selecting roman and math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670326/chemfig-causes-problems-in-selecting-roman-and-math-fonts)). In the included MWE this option is commented out.

Another odd thing occurs when loading the fonts is switched from `typeface` to the `usepackage{font}` option: the first lipsum entry is not printed in `gfsartemisia` but in `computer modern`... Not important as such but really odd as one would expect the same result as `\textrm{}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    typeface=gfsartemisia,
    sanstypeface=tgheros:scale:0.9,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    ]{typeface}

%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
%\usepackage[scale=0.9]{tgheros}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[a4paper,text={18.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

%----- aanvullende pakketten ----
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    {\fontfamily{gfsartemisia}\selectfont   \lipsum[1]  }
    
    \textrm{\lipsum[2-3]}
    
    \textsf{\lipsum[4-5]}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't use the standalone class for such example. That is a rather complicated package that only makes debugging more complicated. Use article or book.

Comment: the package uses \MakeUppercase for programming purpose and that breaks with the new \MakeUppercase implementation. Notify the author.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer. Was hoping for a simple solution, but I guess it's more than just that. I will inform the author of the package and hope he still actively manages typeface. BTW - had already changed standalone to article. Guess the update and your comment crossed each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package uses `\MakeUppercase` in an "inventive" way. This locally defines it in a way that still works

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\let\MakeUppercasesaved\MakeUppercase
\def\MakeUppercase#1{\expanded{\uppercase{#1}}}

\usepackage[
    typeface=gfsartemisia,
    sanstypeface=tgheros:scale:0.9,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    ]{typeface}

\let\MakeUppercase\MakeUppercasesaved

%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
%\usepackage[scale=0.9]{tgheros}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[a4paper,text={18.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm]{geometry}

%----- aanvullende pakketten ----
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    {\fontfamily{gfsartemisia}\selectfont   \lipsum[1]  }
    
    \textrm{\lipsum[2-3]}
    
    \textsf{\lipsum[4-5]}
    
\end{document}
```

Note you get a warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/gfsartemisia/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 26.
```

which explains why you get computer modern in that case

`\textrm` uses `\T1/artemisia/m/n/10.95` so the family name is  `artemisia` not `gfsartemisia`.

Comment: As far as I can see, using `\uppercase` and omitting `\noexpand` should be the best approach in the two instances where the package uses `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: @egreg yes certainly, but this was a minimal redefinition to avoid patching the package code.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. I'm not sure that the package is being developed: the current version is marked “prerelease” and dated 2012/06/11.

Comment: @egreg I mailed the author....